# Что означает последовательность \o в PCRE?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, php7, pcre

```
<?php
    echo  preg_replace ('/\\o/',  'O',  'What is Compatible?');
?>
```

Значение, которое извлечет PHP из строки `'/\\o/'` и будет использовано PCRE как патерн, будет равно `\o`. Поскольку `'o'` не является управляющим символом, то экранирующий слэш должен быть проигнорирован и  в результате останется только `'o'`, с которым и будут искаться совпадения. Но вместо этого выдается:

```
Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: missing opening 
brace after \o at offset 1
```

Если мы заменим `'o'` ,например, на `'m'(т.е. '/\\m/')`, то в слове `'Compatible'` строчная `'m'` заменится на прописную `'O'`, что ожидаемо. Если кто-либо сможет объяснить, в качестве чего  воспринимается последовательность `'\o')`, буду очень благодарен.

Версия PHP 7.1.6 (xampp v3.2.2). Заранее  спасибо!  */

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по https://pcre.org/pcre.txt, `\o` используется для поиска совпадений символов по их восьмеричному коду:

```
\0dd      character with octal code 0dd
\ddd      character with octal code ddd, or back reference
\o{ddd..} character with octal code ddd..
```

Проверяем:

```
// 157 - восьмеричный код "о" http://www.asciitable.com/
var_dump(preg_match_all('/\o{157}/', 'What is Compatible?', $matches));
var_dump($matches);
```

Похоже на правду:

```
etki@kepler:~ > php /tmp/pcre.php                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
int(1)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
array(1) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  [0]=>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  array(1) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    [0]=>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    string(1) "o"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Это зарезервированная буква и может использоваться как настройка в конце регулярного выражения. Например:

```
  i case insensitive 
  m make dot match newlines 
  x ignore whitespace in regex
  o perform #{...} substitutions only once
```

Еще один вариант это работать как с восьмеричной системой счисления